# Вывод друзей из ВКонтакте на swift

Tags: ios, swift, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте.

Пробую вывести имена друзей через API вконтакте, но не получается с выводом. Делаю запрос следующим образом:

```
func Friends() {

    //let request:VKRequest =  VKApi.friends().get() // без параметров (выдает все параметры)

    let request:VKRequest = VKRequest(method: "friends.get", andParameters: ["fields":"count"], andHttpMethod: "GET" ) //Задаем параметры через метод VKRequest

    request.executeWithResultBlock(
        {
            (response) -> Void in

                println(response.json)

        }, errorBlock: {
            (error) -> Void in
            println("error")

    })

}
```

В результате получаю следующее:

```
{
    count = 198;
    items =     (
                {
            "first_name" = Nikolay;
            id = 1087;
            "last_name" = Yagodkin;
            online = 0;
        },
                {
            "first_name" = Mikhail;
            id = 2084150;
            "last_name" = Veklenko;
            online = 1;
        },
                {
            "first_name" = Nikita;
            id = 2707624;
            "last_name" = Makhinya;
            online = 0;
        },
                {
            "first_name" = Artur;
            id = 2786367;
            "last_name" = Lankin;
            online = 0;
        },
                {
            "first_name" = Igor;
            id = 2851570;
            "last_name" = Streltsov;
            online = 0;
        },
                {
            "first_name" = Dmitry;
            id = 3016302;
            "last_name" = Veklenko;
            online = 0;
        },
   );
}
```

Пробовал записать результат в массив, а далее работать с ним:

```
var books =  response.json as NSArray

                if let theTitle: AnyObject = books[0].objectForKey("sex") {
                    println(theTitle)
                }
```

Но вылезает ошибка из-за несовместимости. 
Если кто сталкивался, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: это не массив.

Comment: Ну да, исходя из ошибок, я это понял. Пробую следующим образом:

    var books = response.json as Dictionary <String, AnyObject>

но не понимаю, как вывести именно то, что мне хочется, например, id пользователя.

Comment: Нашел решение, но оно через три колена. Помогите упростить код:

var books = response.json as Dictionary <String, AnyObject>
               
                var newBooks:AnyObject? = books["items"]

                let books2 =  newBooks as NSArray

                
                for var index = 0; index < books2.count; ++index {
                    
                    if let theTitle: AnyObject = books2[index].objectForKey("last_name") {
                        
                        println(theTitle)
                        
                    }

                }
Выводит все нормальн

Answer (score 1):

```
let books = response.json as Dictionary <String, AnyObject> 
let newBooks = books["items"] as NSArray
for book in newBooks { 
   let lastName = book["last_name"]
}
```